# Does oracle allow the uncommitted read option?

Tags: oracle

In db2 a query with a 'with ur' clause allows the query to be an uncommitted read and so does the 'with nolock' clause in mysql. Is there such an option in oracle too... If not why??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tom provides a great answer to this: [On Transaction Isolation Levels](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html)

He says:

> The READ UNCOMMITTED
>   isolation level allows dirty reads.
>   Oracle Database doesn't use dirty
>   reads, nor does it even allow them.
>   The basic goal of a READ UNCOMMITTED
>   isolation level is to provide a
>   standards-based definition that allows
>   for nonblocking reads.

...

> Now, a database that allowed a dirty
>   read ... not only does it return the
>   wrong answer, but also it returns ... [an answer] ... that never existed in the table.
>   In a multiuser database, a dirty read
>   can be a dangerous feature.
>   Personally, I've never seen the
>   usefulness of it...
>
> The point here is that dirty read is
>   not a feature; rather, it's a
>   liability. In Oracle Database, it's
>   just not needed. You get all of the
>   advantages of a dirty read—no
>   blocking—without any of the incorrect
>   results.

Comment: Executive summary: you don't need it, because oracle already does the right thing.

Comment: "You don't need it, because oracle does not support it" would be fairer. Dirty reading greatly simplifies the application debugging. Shame that Oracle does not provide this feature.

Comment: Here I would argue that it can be needed. Right now I am running and debugging a complex PL/SQL block and I want to check if table is being actually updated or block froze somewhere. Thanks to Oracle´s idea what is wrong and what I need I was robbed of one tool (albeit rarely validly used). But when it is used in a valid way then it´s priceless.

Comment: If it isn't needed, then how can I answer the question"how many uncomitted rows are being added to the table?"?

Comment: @Jacob - if I was adding the uncommitted rows then I would count them while I was adding them or count them as candidate rows before adding; if someone else is adding them then that's in another transaction and not something you should have any access to or concerns over, which I guess is Tom's point.

Answer (score 5):

Tom Kyte's answer is correct WRT oracle, there is no such thing as a dirty read due to its Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC) architecture.

From the perspective of application functionality, I completely agree with Tom; there is no good reason or dirty reads.

**Why ever use it outside of Oracle?** Where there is no MVCC (e.g. MySQL, Ingres) it is a trick to get around locking problems that can slow performance or cause the locking system to "run out of locks" if not properly tuned. In the same way that you need to tune rollback/undo in Oracle, you need to manage the locking system in non-MVCC databases.

**So why might it be useful with Oracle** -- as a performance boost for read-only functions where "wrong data" is highly unlikely and highly inconsequential. In MySQL/DB2/Ingres/Informix (not sure about SQL Server/Sybase) it can be used to bypass the lock management facility for performance.

Here's an example of a situation where reads do *not need* consistency:

- List of all products

Here's an example of a situation where reads *need* consistency:

- List of products in stock

Oracle just doesn't even conceive of dirty reads, nor could it be "added as a feature" without actually loosing the benefit of performance (i.e. too many tricks would be required to get the dirty data in Oracle's true MVCC architecture).

Comment: yeh but why force people to read your posts with wikipedia up? Just write the full term once and then you can use the abbreviation at will

Comment: Dirty reads are useful when inside a stored procedure you insert records in a log table for debugging or performance check, or to check the steps your long running proc has achieved! How do I read this records with Oracle (like I do in SQL Server with "nolock" hint)?

Answer (score 3):

**WITH UR rationale**:  When it comes to a SELECT ONLY (report) query, it makes no sense to wait for a commit.  If you are reporting on a table that is getting updated, whether you get that update or not is inconsequential.  The dirty read is just as valid as the data after the commit.  Consider if the query were to have hit that locked record a second earlier.

If you run a query against a changing table, you are not getting any set point in time.  The data accessed at the beginning of the query is at an earlier point in time then the data accessed at the end of the query.  There could be numerous updates to the table that may or may not be included in the query results.

Using WITH UR and other DBMS equivalents, provides for a performance gain as queries do not wait for commits and it doesn't introduce any loss in data integrity.

(ps. Just set up my account so I am not able to comment on other responses.)

Answer (score 0):

While the above answers are truly correct, you can take a look at Autonomous Transactions but keep in mind that they are not recommended and you can take a look at here [Autonomous Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm)  and the disadvantages  here [Autonomous Transactions a Poor Mis-Understood Feature](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1915)
.

Comment: better suited as comment.

Comment: Yes. Your right but since I don't have 50 rep I can't comment. That's why the post.

Answer (score 0):

well, 
UR means uncommitted read across commit boarders of other long running transactions. Dirty read is a old term for uncommitted read.  A read into incomplete physical pages isn't possible in DB2 and I hope in Oracle, too. 
I locate SET ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED, It seems to be possible in Oracle, too. 
From point of getting consistence I prefer READ UNCOMMITTED, because CS might generate serialized different returns of one table because of not reaching values. That might wasn't request by an report or dump. Eg. If you want to know - theoretical - values of transactions that will committed later, too..

https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj41180.html

Comment: This is wrong in the context of the question... the link refers to JavaDB (aka Apache Derby) where the transaction isolation can be set.